# Need to find solution to route major traffic via LAN internet and minor traffice via dialup network

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64

I have lan internet with some proxy server (corporate internet) and usb dial up direct network. I am using win7 prof edition.

I want to control the internet traffic(based on applications & most of it ) to LAN internet and minor traffic to dialup network.

After connecting to LAN and then dialup, always dialup take precedence and hence my lan is not used when dialup it is active. All communication I meant here is IE or any application on windows communication.

Interestingly I could control it manually in firefox, by switching/changing the proxy settings to proxy server on LAN or ip address of dial up connection. But if I try the same in IE it doesn't work and always point to dialup(until it is active)

let me know how to achieve this. I was looking in to route command line tool to solve this but need experts advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Fiddler 2

The free web debugging proxy for any browser, system or platform

Features:
http://fiddler2.com/Features/http-https-traffic-recording

Comment: as far as i know fiddler is used to debug the traffic and i require to route traffic between 2 connections.